# Showing $P^TP=I_n-\frac1n11^T$ if $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}\frac1{\sqrt n}&\cdots&\frac1{\sqrt n}\\&P\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ is orthogonal

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonality

> Suppose
>   \begin{align}
> A=\begin{pmatrix}
> \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}&\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}&\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}&\cdots&\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}
> \\&&P
> \end{pmatrix}
> \end{align}
>
> is a real orthogonal matrix of size $n\times n$, where the matrix $P$ is of size $(n-1)\times n$.
>
> I have to show that $$P^\top P=I-\frac{1}{n}\mathbf1\mathbf1^{\top}\tag{1}$$
>
> where $\mathbf1$ is an $n$ component column vector of all ones.

The choice of $P$ is certainly not unique. The most obvious choice to me is that $P$ for which $A$ is a Helmert matrix:

\begin{align}
P=\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&0&0&\cdots&0&0
\\\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}&\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}&-\frac{2}{\sqrt{6}}&0&\cdots&0&0
\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots
\\\frac{1}{\sqrt{n(n-1)}}&\frac{1}{\sqrt{n(n-1)}}&\frac{1}{\sqrt{n(n-1)}}&\frac{1}{\sqrt{n(n-1)}}&\cdots&\frac{1}{\sqrt{n(n-1)}}&\frac{-(n-1)}{\sqrt{n(n-1)}}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}

I could now verify that $(1)$ holds true for this $P$ but that does not prove anything.

How do I find a general form of the matrix $P$ so that $A$ is an orthogonal matrix?

Or is it possible to prove $(1)$ without explicitly finding $P$? Any hint would be great.

Comment: An aside: the [DFT matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFT_matrix#Definition) is often a easier choice to work with than the Helmert matrix, if you're looking for unitary matrices whose first row is $\frac 1{\sqrt{n}}1^T$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is certainly possible to prove your result without finding $P$.  One way to do this efficiently is to use [block-matrix multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix#Block_matrix_multiplication).

In your case, I would write
$$
A = \pmatrix{\frac 1{\sqrt n} 1^T\\ P}
$$
The matrices $A$ and $A^T$ are partitioned conformally.  As such, we can compute
$$
A^TA = \pmatrix{\frac 1{\sqrt{n}}1 & P^T}\pmatrix{\frac 1{\sqrt n} 1^T\\ P} = \frac 1n 11^T + P^TP
$$
Now, $A$ is orthogonal if and only if $A^TA = I$.

Comment: Sorry, what is conformal partitioning?

Comment: @StubbornAtom "conformal" in this context just means that the matrices can be multiplied (using block-matrix multiplication).  For block matrices, $A$ and $B$ are conformally partitioned if and only if we can multiply $AB$ (i.e. the number of columns in $A$ matches the number of rows in $B$) and the columns of $A$ are paritioned in the same way that the rows of $B$ are partitioned.  In this case, we have partitioned both the columns of $A^T$ and the rows of $A$ into a segment of length $1$, then a segment of length $n-1$.

Comment: Can't believe I did not apply the *definition* of an orthogonal matrix !

Comment: Is there a general form of $P$ by the way?

Comment: @StubbornAtom once you have a particular choice of $P$: for any orthogonal matrix $Q$, we have $(QP)^T(QP) = P^TP$.  I'm pretty sure that every possible $P$ can be attained with some orthogonal choice of $Q$.

Answer (score 1):

We can prove it without explicitly finding the $P$'s.

**Hint:** For block matrices of adequate sizes we have in particular 
 $$\pmatrix{U&V} \pmatrix{C\\D} =UC+VD$$
Apply it to $A^TA=I$.